# create custom html helpers in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've starting programming on ASP.NET MVC Framework a year ago.
Recently. I've learning Ruby On Rails Framework
There is "custom html helper" feature in ASP.NET MVC
So I can create my own html helper

```
<%= Html.MyOwnHtmlHelper() %>
```

I've learned that there is html helpers in Ruby such as

```
<% text_area %>
```

which render at html

I have a question. Can I create my own html helper for rendering my own html?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To create a new helper:

1. choose a name for the helper file, for instance tags_helper.rb
2. create the file in the /app/helpers directory
3. create a module according to the file name. In this case

   ```
   module TagsHelper
   end
   ```
4. define your helper as method

   ```
   module TagsHelper
     def hello_world(name)
       "hello #{name}"
     end
   end
   ```

Now you can use the `hello_world` helper method in your view.

Comment: Does an HTML helper have to be a Module? Can it be a class?

Comment: I know this is old but: to use the built in rails mechanism and have it be automatically available, it has to be a module in the `helper` folder and possibly named correctly. You could use a plain old ruby object (a class) - and then you just have to call it with its full name and `<%=HelloWorldHelper.new.hello_world_tag%>` but the Helper mechanism is simpler and is a convention, and you would just call `<%=hello_world_tag%>`