# Is Rails button_tag really called differently to nearly all other FormTagHelpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Summary: for nearly all FormTagHelpers in Rails (4.1.4) you specify a name for the control, followed by a value. But for button_tag you put the value first and the name afterwards. Is that right? My code works for 20 other tag_helpers and breaks for button_tag because of this. Before I create a workaround for one method I want to check whether and why it's this way.

Detail: I'm adding in a bit of JavaScript to all the controls in a view and an easy way to do that has been to (programmatically) create my own wrapper methods for all the FormTagHelper methods, like text_field_tag, label_tag, etc. My wrapper adds in the JS to the 'options' argument and then passes all the arguments on to the relevant FormTagHelper method. So far so good.

But the JS I add in needs to grab some data from the arguments being used to create the tag. In almost every case, the FormTagHelpers have a 'name' argument, followed by a 'value' argument, followed by some 'options'. But button_tag seems to work the other way round. It wants you to put the 'value' first ('value' being the text you want to appear on the button). After that you can supply the 'name', otherwise it defaults to 'button'. The API docs are very terse but it looks like you have to specify that name as part of the options hash. So what I'm saying is that for almost every tag you can write this:

```
a_tag :control_name, "Visible text", class: "some_class", onchange: 'alert( "hi!" )'
```

but button_tag seems to want this:

```
button_tag "Visible text", name: :control_name, class: "some_class", onclick: 'alert( "hi!" )'
```

Is that right? Only it seems weird to reverse the order for just one helper method. Here are the 'signatures' of all the other tags I'm working with:

```
text_field_tag            (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
color_field_tag           (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
date_field_tag            (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
datetime_field_tag        (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
datetime_local_field_tag  (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
email_field_tag           (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
hidden_field_tag          (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
month_field_tag           (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
number_field_tag          (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
phone_field_tag           (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
range_field_tag           (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
search_field_tag          (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
telephone_field_tag       (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
text_field_tag            (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
time_field_tag            (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
url_field_tag             (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
week_field_tag            (name, value = nil,     options = {}) 
select_tag                (name, options_tags = nil,    options = {})    
text_area_tag             (name, content = nil,   options = {}) 
label_tag                 (name = nil, content_or_options = nil,    options = nil, &block) 
check_box_tag             (name, value = "1",   checked = false,  options = {}) 
radio_button_tag          (name, value, checked = false,          options = {})
```

But button_tag effectively expects 'value' first. Have I made a mistake? If not, is there a good reason why it has to be this way? Or is this just Rails being annoyingly idiosyncratic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all other form-helper, the name is crucial as it determines how the data is sent to the server. For the `button_tag` the name can be omitted.

Comment: That sounds intriguing; can you expand a little? I've got several buttons sitting together, so it *seems* like their name is critical. Am I doing something in a non-standard way, then?

Comment: Nope the name is not critical. If the name is `commit` it will send the content (text) of the button along so you can differentiate which button was used for submitting the form. Unless you use javascript code, pressing a button inside a form will just submit the form. If you use `submit_tag` the name of the button is always `commit`.

Comment: Ahh, that'll be it then. I find standard HTML forms a bit plodding and prefer to collect what data I need and send it using JQuery - something the button_tag wasn't designed for, I suppose.

(Incidentally, the source gives these as the defaults:  

    `options = { 'name' => 'button', 'type' => 'submit' }.merge!(options.stringify_keys)`
[GitHub link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/801e159ce2f4645f6839c94ab0febf97a0d8543d/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L471)

Answer (score 0):

For button_tag the value must be set first. i.e.

```
<%= button_tag "Your Value", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." }%>
```

This is as per the Rails docs.

It cannot be skipped nor rearranged inside the existing button tag.  All code that directly follows button_tag will be treated as the value.  I unfortunately do not have a clear answer for you as to why Rails does it this way.  But you could perhaps change it or create your own helper method to create buttons in the manner that your app requires.

Perhaps check out this SO question to get you started on making your own helper tag if that is the route you decide to go: [create custom html helpers in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797040/create-custom-html-helpers-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm actually making my own 'wrapper' helpers programmatically. But first they all point to the same workhorse method to add in some JS. If all the tags worked the same way I could use the same workhorse method behind the scenes to handle them all, but button_tag isn't cooperating. Excerpt:
    `def MyTagHelper.included(mod)  
      SUPPORTED_TAGS.each do |tag|  
        new_method_name = ('my_' + tag.to_s).to_sym  
        define_method new_method_name do |*splat, &block|   
          my_tag_maker(tag, splat, &block)  
        end  
      end  
    end`

Comment: Oops, can't seem to get my line-breaks to work (double spaces?)