# Restrict title display to admin users - custom html helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have a title in my HTML code that displays text via ruby (by the way, there are many examples of these cells):

```
<td title="id:<%= alert.id %>">Hello</td>
```

I will be creating a helper method (for example):

```
def admin?
  # check if this user is an admin
end
```

How do I use this helper method to restrict the display of the title to the admin user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a helper to check for admin users:

```
def admin?
  # check if this user is an admin
end
```

Then I had to create a custom helper which returns a title for an admin user:

```
def generate_title(this)
    if admin?
      "id:#{this}"
    end
  end
```

And finally update my cell to use the custom helper:

```
<td title="<%= generate_title(alert.id) %>">Hello</td>
```

Its all about the [custom helpers](http://I%20had%20to%20create%20a%20helper%20to%20check%20for%20admin%20users:%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20admin?%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20check%20if%20this%20user%20is%20an%20admin%20%20%20%20%20end%20%20Then%20I%20had%20to%20create%20a%20custom%20helper%20which%20returns%20a%20title%20for%20an%20admin%20user:%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20generate_title(this_stuff)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20admin?%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id:#%7Bthis_stuff%7D%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20end%20%20%20%20%20%20%20end%20%20And%20finally%20update%20my%20cell%20to%20use%20the%20custom%20helper:%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20title=%22%3C%25=%20generate_title(alert.id)%20%25%3E%22%3EHello%3C/td%3E%20%20Its%20all%20about%20the%20[custom%20helpers][1]!%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797040/create-custom-html-helpers-in-ruby-on-rails)!

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
 <td <%="title=\"id:#{alert.id}\"" if admin?%>>Hello</td>
```

Comment: Thats a really nice answer and I will give you an up vote but I am going to implement and accept [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28765775/3507417) because I have many instances of these cells and I want to keep as much logic out of the view as possible. **In my situation**, there will be 20+ cases of `if admin?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= content_tag :td, 'Hello', title: ("id:#{alert.id}" if admin?) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "short-if" variant, to decide what to show inline, inside your HTML tag attribute:

```
title="id:#{admin? ? alert.id : ''}"
```

Read more about the [short-if format](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures#short-if_expression_.28aka_ternary_operator.29).

Comment: Nice answer too Daniel but personally I am going with the helper as I will have lots of `?`s and `:`s everywhere. Thanks.