# Ruby creating title case method, can't handle words like McDuff or McComb

Tags: ruby

The method is supposed to take in a name of a book and return it in proper title case. All of my specs pass ( )handles non-letter characters, handles upper and mixed cases) except the last one which is to return special words like McDuff or McComb with a capital 3rd letter. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? And, is there a way to simplify this, using the tools at hand and not some higher level shortcut?

```
class String
  define_method(:title_case) do
    sentence_array = self.downcase.split
    no_caps = ["a", "an", "the", "at", "by", "and", "as", "but", "or", "for", "in", "nor", "on", "at", "up", "to", "on", "of", "from", "by"]

    sentence_array.each do |word|
      if no_caps.include?(word)
        word
      else
        word.capitalize!
      end
      sentence_array.first.capitalize!

      #  Manage special words
      if (word.include?("mc"))
        letter_array = word.split!("")    # word with mc changed to an array of letters
          if (letter_array[0] == "m") && (letter_array[1] == "c")  # 1st & 2nd letters
            letter_array[2].capitalize!
            word = letter_array.join
          end
      end  
    end
    sentence_array.join(" ")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with your "Mc" code:

```
if (word.include?("mc"))
```

This will always return `false`, because you have already capitalized `word`. It has to be:

```
if word.include?('Mc')
```

This line doesn't work either:

```
letter_array = word.split!("")
```

because there is no `split!` method, just [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-split). There is however no reason to use a character array at all. [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) allows you to access a string's characters (or sub-strings), so the next line becomes:

```
if (word[0] == 'M') && (word[1] == 'c')
```

or just:

```
if word[0, 2] == 'Mc'
```

or even better using [`start_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F):

```
if word.start_with?('Mc')
```

In fact, we can replace the first `if` with this one.

The next line is a bit tricky:

```
letter_array[2].capitalize!
```

Using `String#[]` this becomes:

```
word[2].capitalize!
```

But unfortunately, both don't work as expected. This is because `[]` returns a new object, so the bang method doesn't change the original object. Instead you have to call the element assignment method [`[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D):

```
word[2] = word[2].upcase
```

Everything put together:

```
if word.start_with?('Mc')
  word[2] = word[2].upcase
end
```

Or in a single line:

```
word[2] = word[2].upcase if word.start_with?('Mc')
```

Comment: I have a few points to add to Stefan's excellent answer. 1. The `if no_caps.include?(word); word; ...` part of the `if` statement has no effect.  When `word` is `"and"`, for example, `no_caps.include?("and")` is `true`, so `"and"` is returned, but it is not captured by a variable, so it may as well have been shot into outer space. 2. Since `sentence_array.first.capitalize!` is before `end`, it is executed once for each element of `sentence_array`. Better to write: `sentence_array.each { |word| word.capitalize! unless no_caps.include?(word) }; sentence_array.first.capitalize!`.

Comment: 3. You could use a regular expression instead of `word[2] = word[2].upcase if word.start_with?('Mc')`: `"Mcduff".sub!(/\AMc\K./) { |c| c.upcase } #=> "McDuff"`, where `\K` means to disregard everything previously matched by the regex.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you can probably rewrite the entire method using a single `gsub` call ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please, don't monkey patch. This is bad design, just make a helper function that takes an argument you need (string in your case).

```
def title_case(string)
    no_caps = %w(a an the at by and as but or for in nor on at up to on of from by)
    no_caps_regex = /\b(#{no_caps.join('|')})\b/i # match separate words from above, case-insensitive

    # you will need ActiveSupport (or Rails) for +String#titleize+ support
    titleized = string.titleize
    handle_special = titleized.gsub(/\b(mc)(.+?)\b/i) do |match| 
        [$1, $2].map(&:capitalize).join 
    end

    no_capsed = handle_special.gsub(no_caps_regex) { |match| match.downcase }
end

title_case('mcdonalds is fast food, but mrmcduff is not')
# => "McDonalds Is Fast Food, but Mrmcduff Is Not"
```

**UPDATE**: I am sorry about that, it was really bad reading, but I still want to elaborate on the confused terms you noted:

1. [Monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) is a technique, available for some dynamic languages (Ruby or Javascript, for example) where you can change (add or remove methods/properties) to already existing classes, such as `String`, `Fixnum`, `DateTime` and others. Often this technique is used for "enhancing" core types (exactly like you did in your code, adding method `title_case` to `String`).
   The problem here is that if any other library developer chooses the same name and adds it to `String` class, and you eventually want to try his library in your project,  your implementations will clash together and which one is added later wins (depending on the code loading time, usually yours). This will either brake your code or brake the library which is no good also.

   Another similar problem, is when you try to "fix" some bug in third party library this way. You monkey patch it, everything works and you forget about it. Then 6 months later you decide to upgrade the library to a new version and suddenly everything blows up, because library code clashed with your changes and you may even not to remember about your monkey patch (or it may even be another developer, that doesn't even know about your monkey patch existence).
2. Helper function - is just some function that you can add a) [to a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797084/273444), called helper b) or just to the current controller/model (the place you need it).
3. `\b` is a mark in regex that tells regex engine to treat the following text as a separate word, i.e. `/as/` regex can match for word `as` and also for word `fast` since it contains `as`. If you instead use `/\bas\b/`, only `as` will be matched.

   Regexes are very powerful, please, find some time to learn them, you'll boost your text processing skills to a next level. Combined with some console tools knowledge (I mean commands in UNIX terminals, such as `ls`, `ps`, `find`, `grep` and etc.), they can be very powerful in day-to-day routines such as "whether yesterday logs contain some ip?", "what is the process name that eats all memory on my machine right now?" or "what are all files in my project that contain this function call?".

   The classic book on this subject is [J. Friedl's "Mastering regular expressions"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124), highly recommended.

Have a nice day.

Comment: No idea what monkey patch is. No idea what a helper function is. Not experienced with regex, /\b, etc. Would expect that people with more experience would know I'm a beginner by looking at code. As I stated in the initial paragraph, "is there a way to simplify this, using the tools at hand and not some higher level shortcut?" That is bad reading.

Comment: That was some excellent explaining Shein. Thanks.  I've seen the reference of regex and the /\b/ /\d/ things before, but could never figure them out. I'll study each item you listed today and will take your advice. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan, you were right!

```
str = "Lay on, Macduff, and damn'd be him that first cries, 'Hold, enough!'" 

no_caps = ["a", "an", "the", "at", "by", "and", "as", "but", "or",
           "for", "in", "nor", "on", "at", "up", "to", "on", "of",
           "from", "by", "that", "lay"]

str.gsub(/\w+/) do |s|
  (no_caps.include?(s.downcase) && $~.begin(0) > 0) ? s.downcase! : s.capitalize!
  case s
  when /^Mc./  then s[2] = s[2].upcase
  when /^Mac./ then s[3] = s[3].upcase
  end
  s
end
  # => "Lay on, MacDuff, and Damn'D Be Him that First Cries, 'Hold, Enough!'"
```