# How change simple_form input html tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, vuejs2

Hollow, I need to change input html tag for vue component.
In default config simple_form work like this

```
= f.input_field :name

<input class="string required" id="user_name" maxlength="255" name="user[name]" size="255" type="text">
```

But i need change to

```
= f.input_field :name

<vue-input class="string required" id="user_name" maxlength="255" name="user[name]" size="255" type="text"></vue-input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just using raw HTML in your view?  You are not required to use `f.input_field :name`.

You could just directly write:

`<vue-input class="string required" id="user_name" maxlength="255" name="user[name]" size="255" type="text"></vue-input>`

You could also write your own HTML helper, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797040/create-custom-html-helpers-in-ruby-on-rails).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will be possible easily as they are predefined to be used with Rails. You'll have to create new or monkey patch these methods to behave as intended.